# Why do dates change in DATEDIF when I add a new row o data?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, formulas

I am trying to create an athlete database, using input from the athletes, via a Google Form, which links to a spreadsheet.

Each question on the form corresponds to a matching column on the spreadsheet. Apart from the fact that I don't seem to be able to direct replies directly into the spreadsheet (they appear in a separate sheet) everything works acceptably...

However - and there's always a however - I want the athlete's Date of Birth to generate their current age, so I include another column, which - using DATEDIF - gives this figure.

The column isn't on the form, so I have to create it separately for each new entry - currently well over 700 athletes on the database and more to come.

Here's my problem... I have manually linked the DATEDIF formula for every single athlete, using their DoB cell and the A1 cell as TODAY. They all work.

Until I add another entry. Then, below that new entry, although DATEDIF seems able to keep track of the DoB cell for every athlete displaced by the new row, it also adds a row to TODAY, so A1 becomes A2, A3 if there are two new entries, and so on.

Rather than making every single cell in column A into TODAY, is there a way to apply the DATEDIF formula to stop changing A1 as my reference?

This is the formula I am using: `=DATEDIF(H2,A1,"Y")` my dates are all in dd/mm/yyyy format. The athlete DoBs are all in column H, TODAY is always A1...

This is so far above my head, I seem to have created a beast that I cannot tame, other than by inserting new rows and then re-pointing hundreds of DATEDIF formulae to the correct TODAY cell. And life is too short for that!

Any help greatly appreciated...

Comment: Try using `=DATEDIF(H2,$A$1,"Y")` or `=DATEDIF(H2,TODAY(),"Y")` and next time you might include the google-spreadsheet tag.  They seem to know a lot about cell functions.

Comment: Just to update on this... I have used DATEDIF(H2, TODAY(), "Y") as my format and a) it works perfectly, as well as b) allowing me to drag the formatting down the column to update every entry!

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Use

- `=DATEDIF(H2,$A$1,"Y")` or
- `=DATEDIF(H2,TODAY(),"Y")`

## Explanation

Google Sheets references could be relative or absolute. A1 is a relative reference, $A$1 is an absolute reference.

By the other hand, you could use a function as a function parameter.

Comment: Thanks! I need to tie down A1 as my reference... hopefully, this will do exactly that...